# Copy every 30th instance of range and paste to new range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy from range A4:C4 and paste to P4:R4, i then need to copy every 30 instances of column A-C e.g next value will be A34:C34 then paste to P5:R5, etc until it finds the last row.

This is in VBA, can anyone help!?

Comment: To get you started, this is how you would do a loop with a Step.  A Step performs the operation every x (the specified step) instead of every 1: `For i = 4 to LastRow Step 30`  Then you just need a simple Range.Copy operation: `MySheet.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy MySheet.Range("P" & i)`  Give it a try and if you run into issues, edit your question with the code you've written and exactly any problems, including error messages, encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:C4")     'start copying here
    Set rngDest = ActiveSheet.Range("P4")    'start pasting here
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rng) > 0     'while there's content in `rng`
        rng.Copy rngDest                     'copy range
        Set rng = rng.Offset(30, 0)          'move `rng` 30 rows down
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)   'move `rngDest` 1 row down
    Loop
End Sub
```